# Could one convert a Double Infinite Product into a Double Infinite Series?

Tags: infinite-product

> Could one generalize converting an infinite product to an infinite sum for the case of double products and double series as seen in $(1.1)$ and if possible how would one prove this ?

$(1.0)$

$$\log \prod_n s_n = \sum_n \log s_n$$

$(1.1)$
$$\log  \left(\prod_n \prod_m  s_{mn}\right) = \sum_n \sum_m \log (s_{mn})$$

Comment: I think where you have $s_ns_m$ you mean $s_{nm}$? As it stands, the product doesn't converge, since you have infinitely many factors of each $s_n$ (unless they're all $1$).

Comment: @joriki yes I realized the typo addressing it now

Comment: Now the right-hand side and left-hand side have different indices -- I guess that's also by mistake?

Comment: let $t_n = \prod_m s_{mn}$. Then by applying 1.0 twice, $$\log(\prod_n \prod_m s_{mn}) = \log(\prod_n t_n) = \sum_n \log t_n = \sum_n \log (\prod_m s_{mn}) = \sum_n \sum_m \log s_{mn}.$$

Comment: I have no clue what that means